# Indefinite and Definite Integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to learn calculus as part of a catch up course for a degree. Finding the derivative of a function makes sense to me but finding the integral of a function: I just can't get my head around.

This is the question: Find the indefinite integral and evaluate the definite integral from $-1$ to $+1$.

The function is written like this:
$$f(x) = 2x^2 - 3x + 5$$
Could someone break down the method for integration of the above into small steps that I can wrap my head around? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indefinite integral of $ax^n$ is $\frac{a}{n+1}x^{n+1}$ and the integral of a sum is the sum of the integrals of the summands. Have you tried to sit down and work that out? For the definite integral from $A$ to $B$ you evaluate $F(B)-F(A)$, where $F$ is the primitive function (=the indefinite integral up to constants) of your function $f$.

I will add more details if you let me know where problems are arising for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So the first bit makes sense it becomes
$$\frac{2}{3}x^3$$
but for the
$$3x+5$$
are you saying that I just add them together? so
$$\frac{2}{3}x^3 + 8x + C$$

Comment: Oh wait, instead do you treat 3x the same as 3x^1?
In that case it would be $$\frac{2}{3}x^3 + \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 5x + C$$

Comment: This is correct up to a minus sign before your second term. Now can you evaluate the definite integral?

Comment: Yes that was a typo the first + should be a - :)
I think so, what what I gather I write out the same equation 2 times without the constant and replace all the X's in each with the upper and then the lower limit and minus them from each other!

Comment: That is what is to do, yes. But you keep the constants and they cancel out in the calculation.

Comment: $$(\frac{2}{3}1^3-\frac{3}{2}1^2+5) - (\frac{2}{3}-1^3-\frac{3}{2}-1^2+-5) = 8.3333$$

This is what I am getting currently?

Comment: wait my calculator kept -1^2 as -1 instead of 1 for some reason, the answer would be 11.333333367

Comment: Yes, the result is $\frac{34}{3}=11\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be answered by the basic property of integral which states that an integral with a polynomial function will obey a distributive property. That is,

$$\int(f(x) + g(x))dx  =\int f(x)dx + \int g(x)dx$$
so that
\begin{align}\int(2x^2 – 3x + 5) dx & =\int 2x^2dx - \int 3x dx + \int5 dx \\
& = \frac{2x^3}{3} – \frac{3x^2}{2} + 5x + c\end{align}

Comment: So would that be

$$2\frac{3x}{3} - 3\frac{2x}{2} + 5x + C$$ ?

I am struggling to understand your formatting.

Comment: No, the 3 after x is actually the power of x. And so on..

Comment: Ok so my other comment was correct?

$$\frac{2}{3}x^3 - \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 5x + C$$

Comment: I am not able to write in the correct format

Comment: You could avoid that kind of misunderstandings by using MathJax/LaTeX.

Comment: Yes, exactly. since I could not format it correctly, I put it in that way.

Comment: I don t know how to use it.

Comment: @ajanda Is it as you wanted now? If not, you can take a look at [this Meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to find some help with MathJax and edit the answer yourself.